# How to run a project remotely in android?

Tags: android

I have an android project and I want to run the project in an emulator in another computer using eclipse or some other way. Is it possible?

Comment: Read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754162/remote-debugging-with-android-emulator

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  Two possibilities:

1) Run the whole work session including eclipse remotely using X, vnc, or remote desktop

2) Run just the emulator remotely, and talk to it via TCP.  The emulator's TCP implementation normally only listens on the local loopback interface, so you'd either need to modify that or use a port forwarder.  If you use SSH to connect to the remote machine, there are command line options that will set up the necessary port forwarding for you.  You then just tell adb on the machine you are sitting at to connect to an android device over tcp, supplying the loopback interface of the machine you are sitting at and the local port on that machine that you have told ssh to forward to the local port on the remote machine where it's emulator is listening.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer Chris. Can you please provide me an example of the second method you mentioned.

Comment: See the adb docs for how to connect to a local emulator over tcp, and the ssh docs for how to set up a port forward.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Source Control Version like SVN, TFS? you can upload your project in a server that can be access it throught different machines with your eclipse. I think this is the best way to work remotely. If you have more data about your conditions I can edit my answer to best fit your needs.