# How to debug a website on Android?

Tags: android, debugging, mobile, browser

I don't have an Android phone or tablet, and it seems that on some Android devices using stock browser my website is stuck for half a minute until it loads.

I've been testing with various emulators found online like BrowserStack, etc. The browser is just stuck for a while. That's not the case for iPhone or desktop.

How can I debug this issue? How can I see a developer console or errors or figure out what's causing the slowness?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug javascript on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) with Chrome for Android if the problem happens on this browser (which is the default browser on recent Android versions)

How to use [Remote Debugging with the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754162/remote-debugging-with-android-emulator)

---

If the issue only occurs with the *legacy* Android browser, you might be able to get some information by monitoring the http requests with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

How to use [Fiddler with Android](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid)

Comment: I thought he didn't had an Android device? Without an android device, he can't remote debug, right? At leats one of the devices needs to be an android.

Answer (score 1):

These links will help you debug code in general without having a physical android.

Android studio user guide on debugging: [Start](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html), [Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html) and [Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html).

[Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).