# Remote debugging with Visual Studio Mac

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-mac

Is it possible to use remote debugging with Visual Studio Mac? There aren't any [remote tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) listed but I was wondering if it's possible in some other way to connect to a remote running instance of the application from Visual Studio Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the answer is no, but that the feature "suggestion has been queued up for prioritization", per [Visual Studio Developer Community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/949470/remote-debugging-visual-studio-for-mac.html).