# How to connect an Android Virtual Machine as Android Emulator on VS Code on Mac?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, proxmox

I'm on a computer client that has a Ryzentosh "a PC with an AMD Ryzen processor running macOS".

Everything works fine here even iOS Simulator, but Android Emulator doesn't work, despite it needs an Intel processor and its virtualization technology Vt-x; that is not the same as SVM from AMD.

I've heard that it's possible to connect to a physical android device or a Virtualized Android device via IP, in order to use it as an Android Emulator for coding with Android Studio or Visual Studio Code.

In my case, I have an Android Virtual Machine and I want to use it as I told you.

How can that be done?

I want to use an Android VM as an Android emulator

Comment: Possibly related: [Remote debugging with Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1754162/295004)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Proxmox?